# How did someone with 1 rep reject my suggested edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I made a suggested edit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12971613) and realized it got rejected. So I decided to look why, and what I could improve on, and found out that one of the users that rejected it has 1 rep: User [hhhaaa1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6575698/hhhaaa1)

Is this a bug? How did someone with 1 rep reject my edit suggestion?

Comment: It was rejected by OP. Since he has full control over his own post, he can do whatever he wants, including approving/rejecting edits.

Comment: While this is certainly not a community consensus, many users agree that edit a post **just** to remove "thanks" is a waste of time for everyone involved since you need 3 reviewers to review your post. Find more to edit, or don't edit it at all.

Comment: Even one rep users have powers to overrule you, depending on the situation.

Comment: The alternative to current resolution would be "reject and edit", but it is still reject as "too minor/does not make post any better".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the creator of a post, you have a [binding vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/295232) on approving/rejecting an edit - even if you normally don't have the needed reputation to review edits. An edit on your own post also allows you (if you have >2k reputation) to review it, even if you already made the maximum of 20 suggested edits that day.

Also, while [removing fluff is encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts), don't be surprised if people reject the edit as 'too minor' (like the other two reviewers did). It's probably hard to improve this post more unless you're proficient in [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), but there are plenty of questions around which you can make *a lot* better.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I was editing things like this because of the link you posted. Sometimes they get rejected, but most of the time it seems they don't. So I guess I'll just keep following what that link says. I appreciate the clarification.

Comment: There's no "too minor" reject reason. Also, "thank you"s aren't up to a canonical source of information quality standards.